# How to query last version of JournalArticle with DynamicQuery in Liferay 7.2

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7, dynamicquery

I have the following query in my code:

```
DynamicQuery journalArticleDynamicQuery = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();

journalArticleDynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("DDMStructureKey").eq("MY_STRUCTURE")); 
journalArticleDynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName(Field.GROUP_ID).eq(groupId));
journalArticleDynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName(Field.FOLDER_ID).eq(folderId));
journalArticleDynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName(Field.STATUS).eq(0));
journalArticleDynamicQuery.addOrder(OrderFactoryUtil.desc(Field.DISPLAY_DATE));

JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(journalArticleDynamicQuery, 0, 30)
```

But this is returning all versions of the JournalArticle. My question is: how can I query only the latest version of the JournalArticle using the previous query?

I have posted this in the [Liferay Foruns](https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/117521407) but I didn't get any response yet.

Comment: +1 just for crossreferencing ;). In the meantime the discussion has started on the linked Liferay forum thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that if you use the "search" method and pass the "version" parameter as null, you get only the latest versions of the JournalArticle:

```
List<JournalArticle> journalArticles = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.search(
    themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), 
    themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 
    folderIds,
    JournalArticleConstants.CLASSNAME_ID_DEFAULT,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    "MY_STRUCTURE",
    null,
    myDate,
    null,
    0,
    null, 
    true,
    startIndex,
    endIndex,
    OrderByComparatorFactoryUtil.create("JournalArticle", Field.DISPLAY_DATE, false)
);
```